# SendInput and 64bits

Tags: .net, pinvoke, 64-bit, sendinput

Below is an extract of some code I am using to simulate key presses via the SendInput API. This works correctly if I set my application to compile for an x86 CPU, but doesn't work for x64 CPU compilation.

I'm guessing it has something todo with the fact that x64 uses double size pointers, but I tried to change this `[FieldOffset(4)]` to this `[FieldOffset(8)]` but it didn't work.

Could it be something to do with the fact it is importing the 32bit version of user32.dll?

```
    #region SendInput API

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendInput", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetMessageExtraInfo", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetMessageExtraInfo();

    private enum KeyEvent
    {
        KeyUp = 0x0002,
        KeyDown = 0x0000,
        ExtendedKey = 0x0001
    }

    private struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        public ushort wVk;
        public ushort wScan;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public long time;
        public uint dwExtraInfo;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 28)]
    private struct INPUT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public uint type;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public KEYBDINPUT ki;
    };

    #endregion

    public void sendKey(KeyCode Key)
    {
        INPUT[] InputList = new INPUT[2];

        INPUT keyInput = new INPUT();
        keyInput.type = 1;

        keyInput.ki.wScan = 0;
        keyInput.ki.time = 0;
        keyInput.ki.dwFlags = (int)KeyEvent.KeyDown;
        keyInput.ki.dwExtraInfo = (uint)GetMessageExtraInfo();
        keyInput.ki.wVk = (ushort)Key;

        InputList[0] = keyInput;

        keyInput.ki.dwFlags = (int)KeyEvent.KeyUp;

        InputList[1] = keyInput;

        SendInput((uint)2, InputList, Marshal.SizeOf(InputList[0]));
    }
```

Comment: Somehow, some code was missing so the line in question should read `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 28)]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Further to the error that SLaks identified, your remaining problem is that the size of `INPUT` is incorrect. This means that `SendInput` fails since it receives a parameter of type `INPUT[]`. You can't specify the size with `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 28)` since you want code that handles both x86 and x64.

This all stems from the fact that you have only included the the `KEYBRDINPUT` struct in `INPUT`.  The `MOUSEINPUT` struct is larger than `KEYBRDINPUT` which is the cause of your problem.

The best solution is to define the INPUT structure correctly, including the union part.  Do this like so (declarations taken from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendInput)).

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MOUSEINPUT
{
    public int dx;
    public int dy;
    public uint mouseData;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct KEYBDINPUT 
{
     public ushort wVk;
     public ushort wScan;
     public uint dwFlags;
     public uint time;
     public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct HARDWAREINPUT
{
     public int uMsg;
     public short wParamL;
     public short wParamH;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct MouseKeybdHardwareInputUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public MOUSEINPUT mi;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public KEYBDINPUT ki;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct INPUT
{
    public uint type;
    public MouseKeybdHardwareInputUnion mkhi;
}
```

Comment: There was a reason I had to use SendInput when I started this project but I can't remember why. However - this works! Thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 5):

`dwExtraInfo` is a pointer.
Therefore, it needs to be 4 bytes wide in 32-bit code and 8 bytes in 64-bit code.

To do that in C#, use `IntPtr` (not `uint`, which is always 4 bytes)

Comment: I tried changing this but it DIDN'T work with x64 again (x86 was fine with the change). Thanks.

Comment: @Ben: Your size is wrong.  The size varies with bitness, so you can't specify it.

Comment: Yes, remove `LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 28` and the `FieldOffset` attributes.

Comment: @David Heffernan If I remove those, neither x86 or x64 work. I believe they are needed. I tried changing 28 -> 32 and the FieldOffset to 8 just to see if I could get x64 to work and it doesn't

Comment: You need to use LayoutKind.Sequential presumably. Is the default LayoutKind.Automatic? I'm not sure.

Comment: @David Heffernan How would I deal with the third parameter of `static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize)` given that I have set `LayoutKind.Auto`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing to change for the 64bit platforms is the `FieldOffset(8)` (instead of 4) of the `INPUT`'s second parameter. There is no need to change or specify sizes for the rest structures.  **This is enough and complete** (note that I use the default `InputUnion` structure instead of `KEYBDINPUT` whereas makes no difference):

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct INPUT
    {
    [FieldOffset(0)] public uint Type;
    [FieldOffset(8)] public InputUnion U;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit )]
    public struct InputUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public MOUSEINPUT mi;
        [FieldOffset(0)] public KEYBDINPUT ki;
        [FieldOffset(0)] public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public  IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct KEYBDINPUT
{
    public UInt16 Vk;
    public UInt16 Scan;
    public UInt32 Flags;
    public UInt32 Time;
    public IntPtr ExtraInfo;
}

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public uint uMsg;
        public ushort wParamL;
        public ushort wParamH;
    }
```