# SendInput fails on 64bit

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, 64-bit, pinvoke

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SendInput and 64bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830651/sendinput-and-64bits)

I'm using SendInput from .NET code (PInvoke). 
code used to work fine on 32bit OS, but now on WIN7 SendInput returns 0, and last error is set to 57 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER).
I cannot compile my code as x86 as I am loaded into a 64bit host. Also, I tried various solutions regarding structure sizes and field offsets, none worked.
These are my PInvoke imports and types:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct KEYBOARD_INPUT
{
    public uint type;
    public ushort vk;
    public ushort scanCode;
    public uint flags;
    public uint time;
    public uint extrainfo;
    public uint padding1;
    public uint padding2;
}

[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern uint SendInput(
    uint numberOfInputs, 
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 1)] KEYBOARD_INPUT[] input,
   int structSize);
```

and code usage is:

```
uint result = SendInput(
       (uint)inputs.Count, 
       inputs.ToArray(), 
       Marshal.SizeOf(inputs[0]));
```

where inputs array contains 1 KEYBOARD_INPUT struct.
this yields in result = 0, and when I check last error I get that last error is set to 57 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER, The parameter is incorrect).

Is there a way to make this work under 64bit host in WIN7 64bit OS? this works in XP...

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the following definitions (courtesy of [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendinput)):

```
const int INPUT_MOUSE = 0;
const int INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1;
const int INPUT_HARDWARE = 2;
const uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;
const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
const uint KEYEVENTF_UNICODE = 0x0004;
const uint KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE = 0x0008;

struct INPUT
{
    public int type;
    public InputUnion u;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct InputUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public MOUSEINPUT mi;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public KEYBDINPUT ki;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MOUSEINPUT
{
    public int dx;
    public int dy;
    public uint mouseData;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct KEYBDINPUT
{
    /*Virtual Key code.  Must be from 1-254.  If the dwFlags member specifies KEYEVENTF_UNICODE, wVk must be 0.*/
    public ushort wVk;
    /*A hardware scan code for the key. If dwFlags specifies KEYEVENTF_UNICODE, wScan specifies a Unicode character which is to be sent to the foreground application.*/
    public ushort wScan;
    /*Specifies various aspects of a keystroke.  See the KEYEVENTF_ constants for more information.*/
    public uint dwFlags;
    /*The time stamp for the event, in milliseconds. If this parameter is zero, the system will provide its own time stamp.*/
    public uint time;
    /*An additional value associated with the keystroke. Use the GetMessageExtraInfo function to obtain this information.*/
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct HARDWAREINPUT
{
    public uint uMsg;
    public ushort wParamL;
    public ushort wParamH;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetMessageExtraInfo();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);
```

Then, in your client code, use:

```
INPUT[] inputs = new INPUT[]
{
    new INPUT
    {
        type = INPUT_KEYBOARD,
        u = new InputUnion
        {
            ki = new KEYBDINPUT
            {
                wVk = key,
                wScan = 0,
                dwFlags = 0,
                dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo(),
            }
        }
    }
};

SendInput((uint)inputs.Length, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
```