# Using post/sendmessage to do mouse clicks doesnt work

Tags: c#, sendmessage, postmessage, user32

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to simulate Mouse Click in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c)

I have tried

```
Window = FindWindow(null, "untitled - Paint");
PostMessage(WindowToFind, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, location); 
PostMessage(WindowToFind, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, ((int)Keys.LButton), location);
```

location is `100 * 0x10000 + 100` for `100x100` etc. I doubt its wrong. I have tried swapping `((int)Keys.LButton)` with `0`, didn't work. I tried putting `thread.sleep` between `lbuttondown` and `lbuttonup`(well postmessage should wait without `thread.sleep` but whatever) I use `0x0200` for mousemove and `0x0202` for left button consts.

No idea why it doesnt work at all.

Comment: did you try this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c

Comment: that requires window to be in front and actually clicks. im trying to simulate it. (I just read code, didnt see any window stuff so I might be incorrect) still, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

That's correct. [The `PostMessage` and `SendMessage` functions were never intended to synthesize mouse (or keyboard) events](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). They *might* work for doing that sometimes, but it's not something you should rely on because *most of the time* they won't work.

Instead, you should use the [`SendInput` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) to properly synthesize mouse events. Like the other Win32 API functions, you'll need to P/Invoke in order to call it from C#. This definition can be generated manually from the documentation, or easily found [elsewhere on the Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833311/366904). The only tricky part is that you'll need to declare the appropriate structures as well as the function itself.

The [`mouse_event` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260.aspx) also exists in addition to `SendInput` as a way to synthesize mouse events, but as the linked documentation makes clear, this function has been obsoleted in favor of `SendInput`. You should always prefer to use `SendInput` in new applications.

The only catch is that you appear to be trying to send these mouse events to a *different* application. That's going to pose a bit of a problem, as `SendInput` simply injects the events into the keyboard/mouse stream. The application that processes them is going to be the one with the foreground window. Thus, you'll need to set focus to the other window first and ensure you don't run afoul of UIPI.

The code you have is relatively fragile on another level, though: Paint windows change their name as soon as you save the document with a different name. And that assumes that Windows 9 doesn't rename Paint to something else—it's happened before, the app used to be known as "Paintbrush". Hopefully this is just a sample of something you're trying to accomplish. Either way, I might recommend that you look into more robust methods of automation (e.g., the [Microsoft UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) framework) instead of blindly injecting input.

Comment: Ah I was just trying it with paint. sendinput seems to require focus, sorry if I misunderstood. Can you elaborate "robust methods of automation" ? "ui automation" seems to be unrelated, as I read its just automated modification of ui ?