# C#: The unmanaged method SendInput does not work with different representation of the structure

Tags: c#, telerik, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

This problem come to me with [Telerik Testing Framework](http://www.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework).
Telerik Testing Framework try to simulate mouse click using method [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) to interact with application, but mouse click does not occur.

Under hood telerik code looks like

```
       [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct Input
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int type;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public MOUSEINPUT mi;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    public static void MouseClick()
    {
        var leftDown = new Input();
        leftDown.type = 0;
        leftDown.mi.dwFlags = 2;
        SendInput(1, ref leftDown, Marshal.SizeOf(leftDown));


        var leftUp = new Input();
        leftUp.type = 0;
        leftUp.mi.dwFlags = 4;
        SendInput(1, ref leftUp, Marshal.SizeOf(leftUp));
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, ref Input pInputs, int cbSize);
```

But if change **Input** structure from **LayoutKind.Explicit** to **LayoutKind.Sequential** all works fine, for example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Input
{
    public int type;
    public MOUSEINPUT mi;
}
```

In my opinion both variant must work,  because in memory they are represented same.

Any idea why **Input** with **LayoutKind.Explicit** does not work?

Answer (score 0):

On a 64 bit system, `MOUSEINPUT` has an alignment of 8 because `dwExtraInfo` has alignment of 8. Which means that the correct offset on a 64 bit system is 8 rather than 4. If you switch to sequential layout then the C# compiler is able to place the `MOUSEINPUT` struct at the correct location.

That said, I don't much care for your version either. The `INPUT` struct is really a size field, followed by a union of `MOUSEINPUT`, `KEYBDINPUT` and `HARDWAREINPUT`. Including only the `MOUSEINPUT` relies on `MOUSEINPUT` having the same alignment as the other two members of the union, and having an alignment greater than or equal to that of the two omitted structs.

I suggest that you use the declaration of `INPUT` found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833311/505088